# How does android save properties set using `setprop`?

Tags: android

In android the command `setprop net.hostname` can be used to set (for example) the hostname. This state is persisted during reboots. Where is it saved though?

The `/system/build.prop` file is not being modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setprop` command calls the Bionic function [`__system_property_set()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-8.1.0_r9/libc/bionic/system_properties.cpp#1261), which sends a `PROP_MSG_SETPROP` command with the property name and new value to a socket `/dev/__properties__`.

This is read by the property_service which is part of `init`.  If the property name starts with 'persist.', the message is parsed, and assuming various persmissions checks pass, it will call [`write_persistent_property()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-8.1.0_r9/init/property_service.cpp#121), which writes the data to a file in the `/data/property` directory.  When the system reboots it will read the files in this directory to override the default property values.

It wouldn't be able to modify the default initial values in `/system/build.prop` as `/system` is mounted read only.